# "Method Not Allowed The method is not allowed for the requested URL" even with methods = ["POST"] enabled?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, electron, localhost

In a render.html file I have a button that calls a function in render.js (I included render.js as src in script)

`<button type="button" onclick="someFunc()">Calculate</button>`

In render.js someFunc() makes a request

```
options =  {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
           "Content-Type" : "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(feat1dataObj)
    }

    const test1 = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/analyzeInput', options)
```

app.py is the backend that should handle the request

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__);

@app.route('/analyzeInput', methods = ['POST'] )
def analyzeData(res):
    part1Len = request.json['part1Len']
    print(part1Len);
    res = jsonify( {"Testing":"1"} )
    res.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    res.headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST')
    return res;


#start server
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True);
```

But I get 405 ""Method Not Allowed  The method is not allowed for the requested URL"; the typical solution is that method = ["POST"] is not included but I have that.

[GitBash terminal Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYk1q.jpg)

Seems like I'm making a GET request somehow?

Overall, I'm using ElectronJS to make a GUI, just trying to pass data from the GUI to Python script to process, not sure why tutorials recommend hosting; seems like there should be a way a much simpler way to do this.

EDIT:

```
@app.route('/analyzeInput', methods = ['GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS'] )
#def analyzeData(res):
#def analyzeData(request):
def analyzeData():
  if request.method == 'POST': 
    print("entered analyzeInput")
    #part1Len = request.json['part1Len']
    #print(part1Len);
    res = jsonify( {"Testing":"1"} )
    res.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    #res.headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS')
    res.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept')
    return res;
```

Code currently looks like this (I changed analyzeData to analyzeInput; and changed it everywhere so I don't worry about that part). Getting "view function for 'analyzeData' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement" as the internal server error.

Again, pretty sure that the problem is that the request is sent as "GET" not "POST" but cannot find an explanation for this.
[New output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ms2hr.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It's cross site origin(CORS) issue. From your code I can see you have already taking care of that but in the app.route add options like this:
`@app.route('/analyzeInput', methods = ['POST',  'OPTIONS'] )` . The reason is that the browser rewrites the request and changes the request method to options in compliance to the  cross site origin(CORS) policy that took effect in 2014.

Comment: I tried the suggestion in methods = [] and got the same error; plus I added to ```res.headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS')``` as well but it still didn't work

Comment: in your analyseData view function I'm seeing this res.headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST'); you are setting and not adding, though you can completely remove that line, there is no need for it since you have already allowed the request method in methods=[]. And please post the errors.

Comment: Made your suggestions and it seems to have gotten rid of 405 error code; but still get 500 internal server error. Look at the new image I posted, the pink is a GET request no? Then the if statement is being completely skipped and return nothing -> throwing the error "The view function for 'analyzeData' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement."

I just don't know why it is a GET request.

Comment: sorry it's coming late; you are sending the request in the wrong way. check this site: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-and-post-method-using-fetch-api/ . Note: your method shouldn't be option but still the normal post method.

Comment: As for the internal server error, you are sending the post request in the wrong way, that way is more like a get request and that is why you are getting an internal server error because the view function is not designed to return something on get request.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @john mba’s answer you should add `mode: “cors”` to your options

Comment: You mean add to ```options =  { method: "POST", headers: ...}``` ? I tried that suggestion and I'm still getting same error.

Comment: Yes. Eh, what happens if you also allow GET requests in your flash backend? Then you should explicitly check for an POST request in your Python code with ```if request.method == “POST”:``` and in the following block execute all the code you want to in an POST request.

Comment: tried your suggestion and got internal server error. Tbh I think the lead clue is in the console output/in the attached pic? Isn't it sending a GET request instead of POST somehow?